# navbar with logo in the middle, it disappears when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code, but when I change the size of the window to test the responsive, the logo disappear, only showing the hamburger icon for the accordion menu.

I really want to know how to keep the image logo in the middle when its full width and stay in the middle when collapsed for responsive design.
Thanks!

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#site-logo {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  bottom: -35px;
}

#site-logo a {
  margin-top: -53px;
}

#container,
.navbar .navbar-default {
  border-top: 2px dotted blue;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted blue;
  background-image: url("img/fondo_menu_nav.jpg");
  background: url('img/fondo_menu_nav.jpg');
  font-style: zapfino;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="navbar-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Nav</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav center-block">
        <li class="active"><a href="acne.html">EL ACNÉ</a></li>
        <li><a href="productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
        <li id="site-logo" class="hidden-xs">
          <a href="index.html"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="img/fondo_logo_barrocutina.png" width="150%" alt="IMAGE LOGO"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="participa.hmtl">PARTICIPÁ</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your list item that contains the logo has a class of `hidden-xs`, which is a bootstrap responsive utility class. Its going to hide that `li` at the xs breakpoint.

Comment: yes it does. thats because i want the logo in the middle. If i delete that class, the logo appears in the middle of accordeon when responsive.

Comment: also i would like to add a background image at the navbar, but the image replicates in every button instead the whole navbar.

Comment: i want to make this navbar in bootstrap: http://www.barrocutina.com.ar

Comment: If you look at the navbar component, you'll notice that it has two elements inside `.container`, `#navbar` and `.navbar-header`. either one shows at different breakpoints.  If you want the logo to appear in both then you need to put it in both.